# Using LMDB-tools on an existing database

Tags: python, lmdb

I already have a LMDB-database for example: lmdb.db.
I'm trying to use some tools that already exist and I also accomplish doing this when I first create a new db with these tools. (I got some explaining on how to setup everything over [here: https://lmdb.readthedocs.org/en/release/](https://lmdb.readthedocs.org/en/release/).)
But I don't manage to do this on an existing db.

```
env = lmdb.open('/test', max_dbs=10)
db1 = env.open_db('lmdb.db')
```

This is what I tried, but it always creates a new db. I can't get my own existing one into it. Is it possible, if yes how?

Or is it because I have a .db-file and they want a .mdb-file. If yes, how can I convert them on the command line? (I already found some programs I could download but I want to make some script to easily modify my db and get some stats.) And what do I need afterwards to really open that existing file instead of a new one?